# Cancel image upload to Facebook from iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, cocoa-touch

I have an app that uploads an image to Facebook. this is the part of my code that does that:

```
[[self appDelegate] facebooking]; // checke that the user is loged in
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               labeledImage, @"source",
                               FB_IMG_POST_TITLE,@"message",
                               nil];

[ [[self appDelegate] getFacebookVar] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/me/photos?access_token=%@", self.appDelegate.getFacebookVar.accessToken] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I want to

A) make the upload process a different thread.

B) Give the user the option to cancel the upload.

How would I do that?

Comment: I love the line: if( [[self appDelegate] facebooking] )! Brilliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are not using the facebook SDK correctly. You should not need to explicitly add the access_token. Please see the sample code for this.

You shouldn't need a different thread, the request will be handled asynchronously. What made you think you need to do this?

I'm not sure you can do B) by default. You could change the sdk source to give access to the NSURLConnection (which you can cancel).